# Bootstrap Card extending outside parent element

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to recreate Bootstrap's Cards example in my project. But I noticed that each Card's top margin extends outside the parent element, a `border` div.

Bootstrap docs on `Card` usage [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/card/#grid-cards), picture below for visual reference:

[image]

I've copied the code but my `Card`s get generated as follows:

[image]

I want that "gap" between the border & the `Card`s but in my code example, the border is hugging the `Card`s. I know the `CSS` styling on the `Card`s will make each `Card` have a top margin, but I can't seem to get the border div to fit that margin.

I have tried implementing a margin & padding on the parent element but I still get the same results.

Anyone knows how I can fix this?

Codepen attached here: [link](https://codepen.io/waffledood/pen/KKbGxxL).

```html
<h1>Your Cards</h1>

<div class="border border-1">
  <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-4">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide an [mre].

Comment: @zero298 hi i already included a codepen link in my question, perhaps you missed that

Comment: Your code needs to be in your question, not linked to on an external site.  As unlikely as it seems for Codepen to cease to exist, it would make every question that didn't include the code in the question useless.  Thank you for adding it as text within your actual question.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h1>Your Cards</h1>

<div class="border border-1 p-3">
  <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-4">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Experiment with margin and padding settings on both the parent element and the individual Cards. You may need to adjust these values to control the spacing and alignment of your Cards within the parent container.

added "p-3" class with the "border border-1" class. it create "gap" between the border & the Cards.

Comment: hi Hasan, yes i have tried adding margin & padding to the parent element. the individual `Card`s already have a `margin-top` & left & right `padding`. i have clarified my question, i am trying to visually recreate what is displayed in the Bootstrap docs, where there is a gap between the border div parent & the `Card`s.

Comment: added "p-3" class with the "border border-1" class. it create "gap" between the border & the Cards. please check above provided code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was trying to use Bootstrap's `border` class to wrap the `Card`s & adding `padding` or `margin` to this class. I'm not sure why the `border` class doesn't work.

what i did instead was to create my own custom `CSS` class `.card-container` to wrap the `Card`s & add the `margin` i wanted, code below:

```html
<div class="card-container>
  ...
</div>
```

```css
.card-container {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```